# How can I send role/permission info from project to identity server?

Tags: spring, saml-2.0, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm working on a wso2 webapp project. And I use spring and saml conf on it. I want to sent user's role and permission from the wso2 identity server to my webapp.
How can I send role/permission info from the wso2 identity server to my webapp?

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to achieve here, rather than the technical difficulty. There are scenarios where you have to do similar things. For an example SSO. In such scenarios you can use standard constructs like SAML tokens to pass security related data to Identity provider. (In this case WSO2 IS)

Comment: I examine the some examples about the sso but I couldnt understand  
completely whats its to do about the user role and permission. I want to use my webapp user role and permission. and I know I have to use same user role and permission into the identity server. But I cant send this information webapp to identity server. For example like wso2's application server or esb server . this sserver use saml conf and user role and permission conf. I want to help this part. How can I send or use  uuser role and permission on webapp and identity server. Sory about my english for mistakes.

Comment: OK This is what I understand. 

You are trying to create a web application. You want to get the user's role information from the Identity Server to your web application. 

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, exactly this is what I meant.

Thanks,
Ezgi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to this blogpost. You can try the sample webapp given there as well. http://sureshatt.blogspot.com/2012/11/getting-user-claims-over-saml-sso-token.html

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try it and say  result

Comment: I read your blogspot and thank you very much. Now, I see role and other info